# Clear cache before and after CHMOD

Tags: php, chmod

It seems like PHP keep chmod info in cache. It still the same after an update (which succeed, as I see it in my FTP)

CHMOD before execute : 0505

```
chmod($file, 0705);
echo "1 :".substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4)."<br>"; //print "0505"
echo "2 :".intval(substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4))."<br>"; // Another test, doesn't work : print "505"
```

What should I do to get the real current chmod ? Is it possible ?

Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP fileperms](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) manual:

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache()
>   for more details.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php